# How to delete a revision of a file in Dropbox?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I use the following method to delete, but it doesn't work. How to delete a revision of a file in iOS dropbox?

```
DBMetadata *metaDataItem = _removeArr[i];
[self.restClient deletePath:metaDataItem.path];
```

Error:

> Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=404 "(null)" UserInfo={path=app_folder/dropbox.pc, root=sandbox, error=Path '/app_folder/dropbox.pc' not found}

Comment: That's the right method for deleting a file in Dropbox using the Dropbox iOS Core SDK. The error message is just telling you that there's nothing at that path. Check that's the right path for the file you expect and that you're linked to the right account.

Comment: I just want to delete a revision, rather than the entire file, if that is the case, also using this method? My understanding is that this is to remove the entire file rather than to delete a revision, have any questions for me？

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't allow you to delete just a single revision of a file. You can only delete a non-deleted file entirely.